# Security on the web

Tags: javascript, security

I recently realized that code run on the client side (e.g. javascript) can modify files on the client side (e.g. html, css). Isn't this extremely unsafe?

- Why do we allow this?
- What are the risks that the server is exposed to by this?
- What guidelines should the server side follow to secure itself?

Comment: Javascript is not modifying the html and css files, it is modifying the browser's representation of the html and css files.

Comment: This questions belongs to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we allow this?

Because we can't control the client so we don't have a choice

> What are the risks that the server is exposed to by this?

None that didn't exist already (other then a false sense of security held by developers who don't understand the above leading to them writing server side code with security holes)

> What guidelines should the server side follow to secure itself?

Don't blindly trust the client (i.e. don't assume that data (e.g. the value of a hidden input) you send to the client hasn't been tampered with if it gets sent back). If Auth/Authz matters, then perform Auth/Authz for *every* request where it matters.